# 「Python」「mod_wsgi」をApacheで動かす際の設定について

Tags: python, centos

**Q1.指定ディレクトリ以下で「.php」と「.wsgi」を同時に動かすことは可能？**
・「.phpファイル」へアクセスしたらPHP、「.wsgiファイル」へアクセスしたらPythonを動かすことは出来るでしょうか？

---

**Q2.指定ディレクトリ以下の「.wsgi」ファイルへアクセスしたらPythonを動かすよう設定することは出来るでしょうか？**
・現状下記で「Hello World」は表示されるのですが、このやり方だと、表示する「.wsgi」ファイル数だけWSGIScriptAliasを記述しなければならず面倒です

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf

```
 LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
 WSGIScriptAlias /var/www/hoge/hello.wsgi /var/www/hoge/hello.wsgi
```

・下記のような感じにしてapp.wsgiへファイル名変更したらイケるかなと思ったのですが、Forbiddenエラーになりました  
・WSGIScriptAlias は必須？

```
<Directory /var/www/hoge/>

  Options ExecCGI MultiViews Indexes
  MultiViewsMatch Handlers

  AddHandler wsgi-script .py
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.py app.wsgi

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

</Directory>
```

---

**Q3.バーチャルホストとの関係性について**
・現状下記のような感じで運用しているのですが、こことは別に新たにwsgi.confファイルを作成するのでしょうか？
・それとも、既存のDirectory内に新たに処理を追記していくのでしょうか？

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hoge1.jp
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/hoge1/a.hoge1.jp"
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  <Directory "/var/www/hoge1/a.hoge1.jp">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1,Q2 => 可能です。
WSGIScriptAlias は必須ではありません。

質問の設定にあるように、Options で `ExecCGI` を許可し、`AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi` を設定していれば動くと思うのですが、Forbidden となったときのエラーログに何か記録されていませんでしょうか。

あるいは、以下のように、`FilesMatch` で拡張子と紐付けてもいいと思います。
(httpd-2.4.6 / CentOS 7)

```
<FilesMatch \.wsgi$>
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: FilesMatch で拡張子と紐付けたら期待通り動作しました。大変参考になりました！